# Retrieving items from Collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a Collection c, which contains 3 items. I want to assign these 3 items to 3 different variables

```
Collection<Object> c;
var1 = firstItem;
var2 = secondItem;
var3 = thirdItem;
```

How can I extract the elements of the collection?

Comment: There is no effort from OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as following:

```
Collection<Object> collection = ...;
Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();
Object firstItem = iterator.next();
Object secondItem = iterator.next();
Object thirdItem = iterator.next();
```

Update:
This option is fine only if you are sure that collection contains at least 3 items. Otherwise, you need to check whether iterator has next item (method `hasNext`) before calling `next`.

Comment: Don't forget to check for the existence of a next element, using `iterator.hasNext();` as it may throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: chŝdk, you are right. I have updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: When I do it like this: iterator.next() there is an error
When I do it like this: collection.iterator().next() there isn't 
Can I use the second one?

Comment: What is the error? The second option will always provide first item.

Comment: Found: 'java.lang.Object' , required 'android.os.Parcelable'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you :

```
Object[] array = c.toArray();
Object var1 = array[0];
Object var2 = array[1];
Object var3 = array[2];
```

Note `toArray()` return an array of Object so in case of another Type you have to cast the result for example or you can use :

```
Collection<String> c = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
String[] array = c.toArray(new String[c.size()]);
String var1 = array[0];
String var2 = array[1];
String var3 = array[2];
```

---

Or with a List

```
Collection<String> c = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<String> list = (List<String>) c;
String var1 = list.get(0);
String var2 = list.get(1);
String var3 = list.get(2);
```

Comment: I think that Invoking `toArray()` for each item is not a good idea from performance perspectives.

Comment: Thank you @TimurLevadny this is correct I just fix it